# openpyxl group columns with "Summary Columns to the Right of Detail" unchecked

Tags: python, grouping, openpyxl

in Python I want to group a set of columns and have it behave as if the checkbox "Summary Columns to the Right of Detail" in excel under data->outline would be unchecked.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet()
ws = wb.active

ws['A1'] = 1
ws['B1'] = 2
ws['C1'] = 3
ws['D1'] = 4
ws['E1'] = 5
ws.column_dimensions.group('B','E')
```

I know already how to group columns but can't find a way to give the group the behavior I need.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Not sure why this had been down voted, it's a valid question, I had the same.  Thanks for posting and for finding the answer, which I also up voted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is found the answer. The following line solves the problem:

```
ws.sheet_properties.outlinePr.summaryRight = False
```